# string or binary data would be truncated error message

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error message:

> string or binary data would be truncated

I've tried increasing the column size but no luck, I've doubled checked by code but cant seem to find any issues. Its during an insert:

```
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT 
into orderDetails 
(orderID, Name, Phone, Mobile, Email, DelName, DelRoad, DelTown, DelCity, DelCounty, DelPostCode, BilName, BilRoad, BilTown, BilCity, BilCounty, BilPostCode) 
values 
(@orderID , @Name , @Phone , @Mobile , @Email , @DelName , @DelRoad , @DelTown , @DelCity , @DelCounty , @DelPostCode , @BilName , @BilRoad , @BilTown , @BilCity , @BilCounty , @BilPostCode)", connection);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", ID);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", customer.Phone);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", customer.Mobile);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", customer.Email);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelName", customer.DelName);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelRoad", customer.DelRoad);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelTown", customer.DelTown);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelCity", customer.DelCity);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelCounty", customer.DelCounty);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelPostCode", customer.DelPostCode);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilName", customer.BilName);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilRoad", customer.BilRoad);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilTown", customer.BilTown);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilCity", customer.BilCity);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilCounty", customer.BilCounty);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BilPostCode", customer.BilPostCode);
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here is my table definition code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orderDetails] (
    [orderID]     INT         NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Phone]       NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [Mobile]      NCHAR (15)  NULL,
    [Email]       NCHAR (15)  NULL,
    [DelName]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [DelRoad]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [DelTown]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [DelCity]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [DelCounty]   NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [DelPostCode] NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilName]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilRoad]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilTown]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilCity]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilCounty]   NCHAR (100) NULL,
    [BilPostCode] NCHAR (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([orderID] ASC)
);
```

Customer Class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DelName { get; set; }
    public string DelRoad { get; set; }
    public string DelTown { get; set; }
    public string DelCity { get; set; }
    public string DelCounty { get; set; }
    public string DelPostCode { get; set; }
    public string BilName { get; set; }
    public string BilRoad { get; set; }
    public string BilTown { get; set; }
    public string BilCity { get; set; }
    public string BilCounty { get; set; }
    public string BilPostCode { get; set; }
    public bool sameasDel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post the error message you're getting, and if possible some example values for the `customer` object that cause the error?

Comment: Can you post the values in Customer object?

Comment: The error I'm getting is the one in the title, and it occurs at the ExecuteNonQuery. Customer is a class that a cast from a session like so; Customer customer = (Customer)Session["order"]; - the customer class is on the main post

Comment: Increase the size of `Email` column and check.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you try posting some of the *values* you're assigning to the Customer object that are causing the failure? as Bharadwaj says, it's likely to be your `Email` column, but it would be good to make sure.

Comment: Yeah the problem is the email, thank you all for your really fast help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message is shown when you are trying to insert some data that is too big for the field.

A prime candidate here is `Email` - you only have it set as `15` character whereas most email addresses are going to be much bigger! Increase it to `255` and try again.

Check all of the others too, especially small ones like `Mobile`.

Comment: ah god thanks, I've just set the wrong columns to the wrong types -.- Thank you all

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you see that error

```
    string or binary data would be truncated error message
```

Just understand that you are trying to insert value into a field that cannot hold that value you are trying to insert

```
    [Mobile]      NCHAR (15)  NULL,
[Email]       NCHAR (15)  NULL,
```

they can hold only 15 chars , check yourself if you are trying to insert more than that .