# How can I resolve System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#

When I execute the code this error message occurs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Companyregister";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_name", txtname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Register_no", txtreg_no.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtadrs.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_no", txtphone.Text);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Write("Register succesful");
}
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

What is wrong in my code or my stored procedure that causes this exception and how do I solve that?

Comment: How the SP `Companyregister` is defined?

Comment: Your one of the parameter must have more length than specified in the stored procedure.

Comment: Check the max length of your columns, you might be trying to save a string with 11 characters to a column that takes 10 characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string or binary data would be truncated error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491683/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-error-message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

Answer (score 2):

One or more input values are longer than the specified column length. Either a column is too small or your input is too long.

You could fix this two ways:

- Pass the input always trucated to the SQL

  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_name", txtname.Text.Substring(0, COLUMN_LENGTH));`
- Limit your input fields.*(textbox max length)*  *which I prefer, because the user inputs is never changed when the data is stored. Also the user is alerted on the maximum input size.*

Answer (score -1):

Check the size of columns/fields in the database table. I guess, one of the table fields is not defined big enough to hold the passed values.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to insert a data (string or binary) longer than the maximum length possible for the target field.

Comment: You can increase field maximum length from database 
or 
can set textbox maximum length similar to database field maximum length

Comment: Nice one.  Here's a +1 for you :)